# Psycopg2 concurrency issue

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to do share a psycopg2 connection between multiple threads. As was mentioned in the docs, I am doing that by creating new cursor objects from the shared connection, whenever I use it in a new thread.

```
def delete(conn):
    while True:
        conn.commit()

def test(conn):    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    thread.start_new_thread(delete,(conn,))
    i = 1
    while True:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO mas(taru,s) values (2,%s)",(i,))
        print i
        i = i +1
        conn.commit()
```

After running, I get output like,

```
1
2
...
98  
99
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "postgres_test_send.py", line 44, in <module>
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO mas(taru,s) values (2,%s)",(i,))
psycopg2.InternalError: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. First hit the "edit" link just above this comment. Then enter the code correctly. Then select it all and hit the `{}` button that you see at the top of the input box. That will indent all the lines by 4 spaces, producing correctly formatted code. I would do it for you but I can't tell what the correct indentation would be.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I corrected the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is not in the most recent psycopg2 versions: it has probably been fixed in 2.4.2.

Comment: Yeah. I've been using an older version (2.2.1)

Comment: The bug as reported was fixed in 2.4.2, but its cause was still there, creating less serious problems. Fixed, to be released in 2.4.5. Thank you very much for the report and the test.